# Use Intellij Idea to debug an Easyb .story file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, easyb

I am working on a large project which I need to add additional web tests to.  Our testing framework is Easyb, which I gather is [somewhat old](https://code.google.com/p/easyb/) (around 2010).

My IDE of choice is Jetbrains Intellij IDEA for Java development, and I've gotten the existing Easyb tests running fine inside Intellij.   However, Intellij does not appear to have any support for Easyb.   There's a plugin, but it doesn't seem to do anything besides changing the file type icon from the Groovy icon to the Easyb logo.

Has anyone gotten Easyb story debugging working on Intellij?   If so, how?